# Azure Data Explorer: How do Partitioning Policy and Merge Policy work?

Tags: azure, cloud, partitioning, azure-data-explorer, adx

In our ADX cluster there is no partitioning policy and no merge policy on a table, but the adx still creates extents. I am confused how this works and what the default settings are. Does anyone know this?

Further, how do a combination of partition keys work? For example I have

```
{
  "PartitionKeys": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "tenant_id",
      "Kind": "Hash",
      "Properties": {
        "Function": "XxHash64",
        "MaxPartitionCount": 128,
        "Seed": 1,
        "PartitionAssignmentMode": "Uniform"
      }
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "timestamp",
      "Kind": "UniformRange",
      "Properties": {
        "Reference": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
        "RangeSize": "7.00:00:00",
        "OverrideCreationTime": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This will create on every new tenant_id a partition within the next 7 days? But a limit is 128? Or how should I read this?

And what is the benefit of building this small extents based on partition policy when there is a merge policy which merge the small extents to a bigger one? Why not building a bigger one instant?

Thanks

---

what i did:
searching docs and try to goole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In our ADX cluster there is no partitioning policy and no merge policy on a table, but the adx still creates extents*

if you ingest data, extents will be created (either immediately - if you use batch ingestion - or eventually - if you use streaming ingestion).

a partitioning policy ('null' by default, **rarely required** to define it) will change how extents are partitioned, and a merge policy (defined by default, **rarely required** to change it) impacts how extents are merged.

> *how do a combination of partition keys work? This will create on every new tenant_id a partition within the next 7 days? But a limit is 128? Or how should I read this?*

given the policy you included, extents in the table will be partitioned as follows:

- all records for which the result of [hash_xxhash64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hash-xxhash64-function)`(tenant_id, 128)` has the same value (a value between 0 and 127) and for which the result of [bin_at](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binatfunction)`(timestamp, 7d, datetime(2021-01-01T00:00:00))` has the same value - will be included in the same set of extents, and will have the same partition metadata.
- afterwards, extents that have the *same* partition metadata (for both partition keys) may get merged together, until they reach optimum size (managed by the system). extents that have *different* partition metadata (for either partition key) can't be merged.

> *what is the benefit of building this small extents based on partition policy when there is a merge policy which merge the small extents to a bigger one? Why not building a bigger one instant?*

I would recommend you go over the following posts/documents:

1. [Data partitioning in Kusto](https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/data-partitioning.html)
2. [Extents overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/extents-overview)
3. [Partitioning policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy)

Comment: Thank you. What happen when I set the Partition Key to 7d bin size but in the merge policy the MaxRangeInHours is only 96h or so. Why does it not work?

Comment: MaxRangeInHours prevents data shards that are 'too distant' from each other according to their creation times from being merged. if your RangeSize (7d=128h) is larger than the MaxRangeInHours (96h), this would result with data shards in the same datetime partition not being merged together